# How to drag a custom view to be a private property of a custom view in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I am looking at creating a custom UIView called AnalogClock (from the iOS7 in Action book). I drag out a UIImageView and think I would be able to ctrl-drag to the custom UIView (AnalogView in this case). But I cannot. Do I need to configure anything else to make this possible?

[image: this isn't working]

[image]

This isn't working.

Just showing set to correct custom view (AnalogClock).

Answer (score 0):

You can’t have views that are added in IB be properties of other views. You will need to create a separate xib with `AnalogClockView` as the file’s owner, and then load it from a xib in code like this:

```
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([AnalogClockView class])
                            bundle:nil];
AnalogClockView *clockView = [nib instantiateWithOwner:nil options:nil][0];
```

You may also want to look at `IB_Designable`, which lets you create custom views that render in IB.